# Making simple backup alias / function?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, alias, function

OK, so all I really want to do is backup single files as a time in the current directory with '.bak' extension.

Here is my current function that does this (jsyk, using Rocky Linux):

```
function backup { sudo cp $PWD/$1 $PWD/$1.bak; }
```

Although, Rocky loads it fine (it's inside `~/.bash_aliases` which is loaded from `~/.bashrc`, it seems to keep giving me this error:

```
cp: cannot stat '.bak': No such file or directory
```

Am I missing something? Or am I crazy for not thinking of something even simpler?

Comment: `sudo` requires `-E` and `-H` to preserve environment variables and `cp` requires `-a` and `-f` to keep files metadata and forces overwrite existing .bak

Comment: @alecxs if I’m understanding you, it should be “sudo -EH cp -af …”, if so, didn’t work.

Comment: Well, they aren't local variables, $PWD gives me the current working directory, and $1 I thought was used for posititional variables.

Testing this, I used: ```function test { sudo -EH echo $PWD/$1.bak; }``` Which seems to give me the proper output: ```/home/greg/file.txt.bak```

Comment: You could always use `echo` to get an idea what the command looks like after expansion.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @alecxs, this seemed to work for me:

```
function backup() { sudo -EH cp -af -- "$1" "$1.bak"; }
```